# Single class with multiple constructor parameter values or many classes?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class `Response` which contains a HTTP response with a HTTP status code like 200 or 404 and few other things like a view name and a domain object. But lets focus on the status code. I could use a single class and pass the status as a parameter:

```
public class Response {
  private int status;
  public Response(int status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
}

// in a handler method:

return new Response(HttpStatus.OK);
```

The other way would be to create a new class for every status code (41 status codes in HTTP 1.1). Like this:

```
public class Ok extends Response {
  public Ok() {
    super(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}

// in a handler method:
return new Ok();


public class Created extends Response {
  public Created() {
    super(HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}

// in a handler method:
return new Created();
```

In reality there will be usually more parameters like the view name and the domain object, like this `new Response(HttpStatus.OK, "customer", customer)` respective `new Ok("customer", customer)`.

Comment: Do each status code happen to have different, unique processing or they are all doing the same exact thing except their # is different? If the classes don't bring anything new to the table, don't use them.

Comment: The status are sent to the client but for the server side they are very much the same, with a little exception for error codes which are handled a bit differently from the underlying servlet API, but this is not in the responsibility of the class(es) shown above.

Comment: @David - That would make a good answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself - do you need different "types" for each status code? It could be useful if for example you want to use a specific type say OK as the parameter to some method. If not, I don't see any benefits of the second approach. Go for the first one.

Answer (score 6):

my recommendation
1) if there is no behavior associated with each status code then there is no need for new abstractions.
2) use enums for constants instead of int

Comment: You're right, enums are better. I wonder if I should allow other status codes than those defined by HTTP 1.1.

Comment: define enums that are nearer to your business domain than that protocol specific. If you feel they are protocol specific and still need to have them then u shouldn't be defining new enum constants and treat them as same as HTTP OK etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "pure" way would be to have a type for each distinct value, but in practice this may be overkill.

Generally speaking, consider whether:

- There is any unique processing (which would lend itself to classes)
- Whether there could be a hierarchy between the entities (e.g., statuses representing success and statuses representing errors).

In my experience, if there are hierarchies in the domain, they often end up in the code. You could save future refactoring by planning around that. For instance, error statuses may later also have things like error details tacked on.

My rule of thumb is to look at the specification in which the magic numbers appear. If they are each associated with a lot of details, that could indicate future problems if I merely keep them as ints, since I am essentially using a key to a more complex entity.

Also, when taking details from a fixed domain, an enum might be better than direct int.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the constructor simple. Something like:

```
public Response(int status)
public Response(int status, String reasonPhrase)
public Response(int status, Map<String,String> headers)
public Response(int status, String reasonPhrase, Map<String,String> headers)
```

Or, possibly, omit the last 2 and provide a `setHeader(String, String)`